# How do I check if the user has scrolled down (or crossed ) to a particular element (based on id) in Angular7?

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular7

How do I check if the user has scrolled down (or crossed ) to a particular element (based on id) in the browser so that I can check the condition and assign class name dynamically in angular 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you can listen to window scrolling event with Angular using [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) with `window:scroll` event like this:

```js
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onWindowScroll() {
  // handle scrolling event here
}
```

> Available [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-55777845) for the explanation below

#### ScrolledTo directive

What I would do for maximum flexibility in this case is to create a directive to apply on any HTML element that would expose two states:

- **reached**: `true` when scrolling position has reached the top of the element on which the directive is applied
- **passed**: `true` when scrolling position has passed the element height on which the directive is applied

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrolledTo]',
  exportAs: 'scrolledTo', // allows directive to be targeted by a template reference variable
})
export class ScrolledToDirective {
  reached = false;
  passed = false;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll() {
    const elementPosition = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    const elementHeight = this.el.nativeElement.clientHeight;
    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

    // set `true` when scrolling has reached current element
    this.reached = scrollPosition >= elementPosition;

    // set `true` when scrolling has passed current element height
    this.passed = scrollPosition >= (elementPosition + elementHeight);
  }
}
```

#### Assign CSS classes

Using a [Template Reference Variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) you would then be able to retrieve those states specifying the directive export `#myTemplateRef="scrolledTo"` in your HTML code and apply CSS classes as you wish according to the returned values.

```html
<div scrolledTo #scrolledToElement="scrolledTo">
  <!-- whatever HTML content -->
</div>

<div
  [class.reached]="scrolledToElement.reached"
  [class.passed]="scrolledToElement.passed">
  <!-- whatever HTML content -->
</div>
```

That way you can assign classes on other HTML elements or on the spied element itself ... pretty much as you want, depending on your needs!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you j3ff for you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use "IntersectionObserver" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Create a directive as given below in the example and apply to the element you want to track.  When the element is visible the intersectionobserver will be triggered!

Below is an angular based example to load contents of div (an image) only when the div boundaries are visible.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-intersection-observor

```
<span class="card" *ngFor="let card of data" (deferLoad)="card.visible = true">
    <img src={{card.url}} *ngIf="card.visible"/>
</span>


import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector:"[deferLoad]"
})
export class DeferLoadDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private _intersectionObserver: IntersectionObserver;

  @Output() deferLoad: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private _element: ElementRef
  ) {};

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      this.checkIntersection(entries);
    });
    this._intersectionObserver.observe(this._element.nativeElement as Element);
  }

  checkIntersection(entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if ((<any>entry).isIntersecting && entry.target === this._element.nativeElement) {
        this.deferLoad.emit();
        this._intersectionObserver.unobserve(this._element.nativeElement as Element);
        this._intersectionObserver.disconnect();
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wont work in IE11 https://caniuse.com/#search=IntersectionObserver and it does not answer the original question on "how to add class dynamically"

Comment: are you still supporting IE?  we dropped support for IE long back and its supported only in edge and newer edge is chromium based, so it will definitely work there.